# Removing triples from returned document

Tags: json, triples

I have unmanaged triples stored in my documents. When I return documents using

```
var doc = cts.doc('/document/location/doc.json');
doc;
```

I get my doc, with the triples attached.

```
{
    "name": "Place name", 
    "address": "Place address"
    "triple": {
        "subject": "/document/location/doc.json", 
        "predicate": "contains", 
        "object": "/locations/buildings/A000001.json"
    }, 
    "triple": {
        "subject": "/document/location/doc.json", 
        "predicate": "contains", 
        "object": "/locations/buildings/rooms/offices/A000003.json"
    }
}
```

How do I return the document without the triples? I want to send the results to my middle tier without exposing too much database information.

Comment: What language is this? Your object has multiple `triple` properties, so it is not valid. Depending on who/what is processing it, most likely one of the `triple` properties will be removed/ignored.

Comment: It is not a language, it's a json object. This is how the MarkLogic database stores rdf triples inside a json document. Or at least this is how the database returns the json object when you request a document that has unmanaged triples attached.

Comment: MarkLogic allows you to use JavaScript to interact with the database. cts.doc('/document/location/doc.json') is how you retrieve a document stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

So I suppose cts.doc returns an object and not necessarily a JSONObject. Which I guess makes sense since it has multiple objects with the key 'triple'. So, I just had to parse the object into a JSONObject (which only keeps the first 'triple' object) and then I could get rid of the 'triple' object.

```
var doc = cts.doc('/document/location/doc.json');
doc = JSON.parse(doc);
delete doc.triple;
doc;
```

Now returns:

```
{
    "name": "Place name", 
    "address": "Place address"
}
```